# Central tendency to present in table in relation to hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, central-tendency, parametric

I am doing hypothesis test on the data to compare group A and B and there are multiple variables that I tested.
Due to the distribution of some of these variables is skewed and there are some extreme outliers, I used non-parametric approach, i.e., Mann-Whitney U test. I would like to include the table as follows.

| Significant Variables | Class A (mean/median) | Class B (mean/median) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| var1 | ... | ... |
| var5 | ... | ... |

I understand that the null hypothesis of Mann-Whitney does not necessarily compare median, but the non-parametric central tendency is median. So my question is, if I used Mann-Whitney U test (non-parametric approach), should I present the table with median values? Or is it still valid to present the mean?